# How many Event receivers can we have for a SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

How many Event receivers can we have for a SharePoint List?
All the lists we want to have event receivers on will be used for receiving mail.

Comment: Please add more infomration, why you want this, and what exactly you are trying to do here.

Comment: @Nikunj we have a announcement list which is enabled to receive mail. I want to do some event handling based the subject we receive in mail like lazy approvals from mail. so wanted to know if already suppose 10 event receivers are there to a list can we have another event receiver attached.

Comment: yeah you can, but make sure you are ordering them correctly, they are not infinitely triggering each others.

Answer (score 1):

Practically, as many as you want. You could play with sequence number if priority is important.